# How to use an external xml schema in xslt file?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have uploaded an xml file, and I want to use the schema that is declared in it, in my xslt file:

Xmlfile.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<offerbody>
<header-area>
<intitle>Welcome to our website</intitle>
</header-area>
<content-area>
<offerpic>http://exemple.com/5c55b4213da49.png</offerpic>
</content-area>
</offerbody>
```

Xsltfile.xslt :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <table width="100%">
      <tr align="center" bgcolor="#E3ECEE" style="height:90">
        <xsl:for-each select="offerbody/header-area">
           <td><xsl:value-of select="intitle"/></h2></td>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
<xsl:for-each select="offerbody/content-area">
      <tr align="center" bgcolor="#E3ECEE">
        <td>
           <img> 
               <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="offerpic">
               </xsl:attribute>
           </img> 
        </td>
      </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to upload my xml file to a service, and make the xslt file use it..

is there any possibility to make that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include code as text in a code section and not as image.

Comment: It is not clear in what way you expect your XSLT code "to use the schema". Which XSLT version, which XSLT processor do you use or do you target?

Comment: The title of question mentions an "XML Schema", but there is no mention of that schema in the text of the question? Are you actually asking "How do I apply an XSLT to an XML on the server"? Thanks!

Comment: I just want to add a reference to external xsl file in my xml file, because I want to upload the xsl file on any cloud service, meaning, the files are not in the same folder

Comment: or if there is any idea to make an inline xslt, I mean makes them in the same file, please provide it to me